# Record and replay actions made in Flash application using AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe

i am creating a mobile application for android using Adobe flash. It is a piano app. what i want is to record and play back the activities done by the user using a record button. can you please give some tutorials on how to create this.

Comment: You could always look at the documentation. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each time the user does something, make a appropriate object containing enough data to dublicate the event (also at the right time), and push that into an array. (fx for a "PlayKeyOnPiano" event happening in your application, you should note which key was pressed)

When you want to play back, you simply execute functions based on your recorded events at the right time.

Fx, if you are executing a main a loop on each frame, you could keep an array for events happening in that frame. While recording, for each event encountered, you add that to the array created in the start of the frame. In the end of the frame you add this "frame array" to the "recording array". When you want to play back, you increase a counter each frame, and use that to index the recording array to get the recorded "frame array" to execute upon that given frame.

Comment: If you know enough about ActionScript to have build such an application, this shouldn't be too difficult - and would be a good exercise for you it seems. Else I would recommend reading this excellent tutorial series (event thuogh it a bit old, it's really good): http://gamedev.michaeljameswilliams.com/2008/09/17/avoider-game-tutorial-1/